# Hotword detection disabled with accessibly service

Tags: android, android-service

I've created a accessibly service for saving every toast message, but now hotword detection in Google Now will be disabled, if I activate my service. Logcat shows:

```
W/HotwordState﹕ suspended: 11001001000000
```

And on Google Now you can see it with a different mic-icon.

[image: Hotword detection is enabled/disabled]

What could cause this behavior?

Edit: The source code is on github now: https://github.com/mars3142/toaster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent false positives, hotword detection is disabled when a spoken feedback service is enabled. You have defined your service as providing all possible types of feedback, which includes spoken.

```
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
```

You should change this to reflect only the type of feedback your service actually provides. For example:

```
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
```

Comment: It works very well. Thanks a lot for this hint. I didn't know that and the logcat message was not really a help for me.